# page cache theory - will this work?

Tags: php, header, http-headers, cache-control

I'd like to setup browser caching on my site.  The problem is that the caching will only be for guests, not logged in users.  I know I can throw different headers based on a user's logged in status, but how will the cache treat that?  Do I run the risk of guests seeing user's content?

**update**

What I'm talking about is if i throw a last-modified header for all guests and force a fresh page for all logged in users.  I suppose this would only help so much... I'd like it if all guests could share a proxy cache and all members could stick with fresh pages, but I don't think that would work.

How do both @Victor and @klausbyskov have a +1 on their response, they appear to be saying the opposite things.

Comment: this is a broad discussion, cache of dynamic page? or static files ? or use php to generate static content like images? this is something worth to read about - http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html (as long as user clear cache or force refresh in browser, basically cache won't serve the purpose)

Comment: add header `cache-control max-age=xxx` for non-logging user

Comment: @ajreal - so I should include `must-validate` to prevent logged in user's information from being stored on proxies, right?

Comment: yup. probably add in meta for `Expires`, `Pragma`, `Cache-control` and so on, for proxy cache , not that straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache is **in the browser**. Therefore it is not possible for a guest to see a user's content.

Comment: Whoops.  I originally assumed he meant a server side cache.  This answer is correct.

Comment: What about proxy caching?  Is it possible for me to cache in a proxy only for guests?

Comment: It **is** possible for a guest to see an user's content: user logs in, visits URL, logs out, guest visits URL and sees the user's content still present in the browser cache. This basically makes the site unsafe on any public computer.

Comment: @Victor Nicollet, no. Because the only pages that do not expire right away (and are thus put into the cache) are those that are presented to users who are not logged in.

Comment: @klausbyskov: if guest pages are cached, logged in users will see the cached versions of the guest pages. Not as critical as the reverse situation, but still pretty annoying.

Comment: @Victor Nicollet, correct, but not the problem being addressed here and not what your first comment stated.

Comment: Is it morally unacceptable to document an unspoken and probably unwanted consequence of a given solution, simply because it's not explicitly part of the original problem?

Comment: @Victor Nicollet, no not at all. I'm just saying that a guest will never see a logged in user's content, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

The cache works solely based on the URL, so if your users and your guests use the same URL, the cache will affect both in the same way (meaning that users may not see up-to-date data). Any caching system which prevents the browser from querying your server will therefore cause you problems.

On the other hand, you can have the server detect if cache-related headers were provided, determine if the visitor is a guest or a logged in user, and respond to guests with a 304 Not Modified. This still requires the browser to send you a request, but at least you won't have any server-side work to do beyong sending back a 304 header.